# Select codes only if specific users dont have it

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, having-clause

I have a table that have ASIN codes entries for each user that owns that ASIN.

Example: listed_items table:

```
User_id---asin
12--------B078JKTHRL
6---------B078JKTHRL
16--------B078JKTHRL
5---------B078JKTHRL
87--------B078JKTHRL
90--------B078JKTHRL
```

I want to make a select that only returns ASINs that are not owned by a specific user.
When i do this:

```
SELECT ASIN FROM listed_items ad WHERE user_id NOT IN (5,16,9)
```

I still get this ASIN that is owned by the user 16 and 5, because of course it get's me the asin from other user. And my goal is exactly to bring only ASIN that have no entries for user 5, 16 and 9...

Can you help me wit this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look across *groups* of rows having the same `asin`, which suggests aggregation: use `group by`; then you can implement the filtering logic with a `having` condition. In MySQL, you can phrase this as:

```
select asin 
from listed_items 
group by asin
where max(user_id in (5,16,9)) = 0
```

This generates one row per `asin`. If you want the entire corresponding rows, then that's a pretty different question. I would recommend `not exists` instead:

```
select li.*
from listed_items li
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from listed_items li1 
    where li1.asin = li.asin and li1.user_id in (5,16,9)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM listed_items
WHERE `asin` NOT IN(SELECT `asin` FROM listed_items WHERE user_id IN(5,16,9) AND `asin` IS NOT NULL);
```

Condition: `AND asin IS NOT NULL` is required only if column `asin` is nullable.